# Insert copied row range after skipping the next row

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy-paste

I am not sure if this is possible but I have a spreadsheet of bookmarks from a pdf that I have exported its bookmarks. I need to copy data from Rows 650 and 651 then insert after 652 all the way down to row 805. I can hand insert but if I can get this to work it would be extremely helpful as I have had to do this with a couple of spreadsheets recently.

I made a macro so that I could try to get started with at least some bit of code and then tried to get ChatGPT to help me out with the rest. Here is what it was able to come up with after a few trial and error runs.

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim insertRange As Range
    
    ' Find the last used row in column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the range to copy (A650:Z650)
    Set copyRange = Range("A650:Z651")
    
    ' Loop through the data and insert the copied rows at the desired pattern
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 650 To lastRow Step 2
        ' Check if the bookmark is provided in column B
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
            ' Set the range to insert after the bookmark row
            Set insertRange = Range("A" & i + 1 & ":Z" & i + 1)
            
            ' Copy and insert the range
            copyRange.Copy
            insertRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, please describe exactly what it is that is not working.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Run-time Error '1004": This selection isn't valid. Make sure the copy and paste areas don't overlap unless they are the same size and shape.
When I click debug this is what gets highlighted insertRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Comment: Your loop starts at 650 so you are trying to copy copyRange to itself?

Comment: @SJR Great question as I didn't even put that together. I'd like the loop to start at 652.

Comment: Also I think you will need to loop backwards. As you insert rows you are affecting your loop and everything will be out of kilter.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Sub Test()

Range("A650:Z652").Copy Range("A650:A805")

End Sub
```

Comment: While technically yes it did work it made all of the data the same. so essentially everything was replaced with bookmark 207 all the way down. I keep trying to show sample data but it shows that it is too many characters.

Comment: That's fine, that's how I understood your question and your code. Ok so copy rows 650 & 651, skip row 652, paste them in row 653 & 654. Is that right so far? Then what do you want to do with row 655 and after?

Comment: Hi @kevin I technically want to insert between 652 and 653 if that makes sense. 
sjr that makes sense as things are getting shifted around in a crazy way